# What is the correct way to use 'half as much ...... as' while comparing two things?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is the syntax correct in the following sentence?

You don't know **half as much** about New Zealand **as** you know about Australia.

I am trying to tell that your knowledge about New Zealand is less than half of your knowledge about Australia.

Can it be simplified as follows?

You don't know **half as much** about New Zealand **as** about Australia.

Comment: Why stop there? You can delete ***about*** as well: *You don't know half as much about New Zealand as Australia*.

Comment: Just ’cuz you may know something about Australia doesn’t mean you know anything about New Zealand.

Comment: You do do know about Australia, but you only know half as much about NZ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be simplified in the manner you put. In fact, I believe, that's how most natives use it.

Comment: If the sentence is to be changed to mean that your knowledge about New Zealand is less than half of "my" knowledge about Australia, I will have to use the entire sentence, right? - You don't know half as much about New Zealand as I know about Australia.

Comment: Yeah. That's true.